# Use Python extensions with Chrome native client

Tags: python, swig, google-nativeclient

I have an application written in Python and C++.  I use SWIG to wrap the C++ parts.  I'm interested in porting this application to work with Chrome native client (NaCl and/or PNaCl).  I see that Python 2.7 is listed on the naclports page, so presumably it won't be a problem to run the Python code.  But does it support C extensions?  Will it be able to load my SWIG wrapper when running under native client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the python port (BTW there is 2.7 as well as 3.3) in naclports supports C extensions. There are several in naclports already (see ports/python_modules).

I don't know if any of them use swig by I don't think that would be a problem.